# Is Java's Runtime class a proper example of a Singleton?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I have been reading about singleton pattern for a while now and when I searched for Singleton classes in Java language I found Runtime as an example but when I looked into the source I found a very basic Singleton implementation:

```
private static Runtime currentRuntime = new Runtime();
public static Runtime getRuntime() {
    return currentRuntime;
}
private Runtime() {}
```

Whereas on the internet there is a lot written about how a singleton class should be. What I wanted to know is which of the Java language classes is best fit as a Singleton class example and why?

Comment: do you see any possibility to create more than one instance of this class? if no, it is a proper example

Comment: There are a lot of ways in which you can implement singleton design pattern. The way `Runtime` implements it is just one of the way.

Comment: why you want to know which java class is best fit? same things has different ways to do as per requirement in single threaded app no need of synchronized, in multi threaded u need synchronized but you make to take a call if you want to synchronize block of method, etc

Comment: Beware of looking for nails because you have a hammer.

Comment: @VedX The reason I wanted to know the best fit is because this is a questions people tend to ask a lot in interviews so I am looking for an answer which I can properly explain and defend in different scenarios

Comment: @Stultuske I haven't tried yet to create another instance of this class but as far I know in multi threaded environment this class can behave differently

Comment: @YogeshBadkev true thanks.

Comment: @EshantJain knowing scenarios will definitely help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a very basic singleton. It does what it's supposed to do with no special frills.

The examples you find on the internet usually describe a lazy initialized singleton with emphasis on the performance of `getInstance()` (i.e. avoid synchronized, don't allow creating multiple instances if multiple threads call `getInstance()` at the same time and so forth).

If you don't need lazy initialization it becomes very simple to create a singleton, as you can see with `Runtime`.

Finally, you can find a lot of things written about the singleton pattern (some of them misleading), but it doesn't really warrant it. It's not **that** interesting, some consider it an anti-pattern, and if you find yourself writing your own singletons a lot, you're probably doing something not quite right.

Extra finally, if you do think you need a lazily initialized singleton, the current standard implementation is with `enum`.

```
public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE

    public String getSarcasticMessage() {
        return "I'm a lazy loaded singleton, use me for everything!";
    }
}

MySingleton.INSTANCE.getSarcasticMessage();  // This is how to use it
```

Comment: `Runtime` *has* lazy initialization, as the initialization does not happen before one of the [specified initialization triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1), which is the first invocation of `Runtime.getRuntime()` in practice. Note that this is exactly the same mechanism making the `enum` initialization lazy. The only difference is that the `enum` declares `public static final ` field(s) for the constants, which adds the possibility to trigger the class initialization via access to a `static` field.

Comment: Enums are better singletons since you can't circumvent Singleton by Reflection, Serialization, etc.